# find can not find size between A and B

Tags: linux, find, ls, size

### problem description

I was using find(GNU version) to find files with size between 4G - 5G with below command

```
# find . -size +4G -size -5G -exec ls -1hSs {} +
```

But below can work

```
# find . -size +4G -size -6G -exec ls -1hSs {} +
4.9G ./ff84e49c231a00b2d7ed40e0ecf81cad220795bd
4.5G ./ff623cd1cdad094be418aec445e5317156e945fe
```

I read the man page of find get below:

```
         `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)

          The  size  does  not count indirect blocks, but it does count blocks in sparse files that are not actually allocated.  Bear in mind that the `%k' and `%b'
          format specifiers of -printf handle sparse files differently.  The `b' suffix always denotes 512-byte blocks and never 1024-byte blocks, which is  differ‐
          ent to the behaviour of -ls.
```

And man page of ls get below but still got confused:

```
          -h, --human-readable
          with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)       
          The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is 10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,... (powers of 1000).
```

Comment: I'm not posting a full answer because I believe the question is a duplicate. A comment tailored to your case: when the unit is `G`, a given size is rounded to some *integer* number of gibibytes. This number cannot be greater than 4 (`+4G`) and less than 5 (`-5G`) at the same time. No such integer exists. OTOH `+4G` and `-6G` are both satisfied when the number happens to be 5.

Comment: Thanks Maciorowski for the info!